# a' the world's gang agley

Tags: meaning-in-context, dialects

> Toward the close of her life she was greatly troubled at any unusual
> stir in the household. She liked to have company, but nothing
> disturbed her more than to have a man working in the cellar, putting
> in coal, cutting wood, or doing such work. She used then to follow us
> uneasily about and look earnestly up into our faces, as if to say:—
>
> "Girls, this is not right. Everything is all upset here and 'a' the
> world's gang agley.' Why don't you fix it?"
>
> — [*Concerning Cats*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nkpPAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29) by Helen M Winslow 1900

I feel like "a' the world's gang agley" is a kind of dialect. Can I change it into "all the world is gang agley"?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "all the world *has* gone agley"? Which itself doesn't sound right unless you replace "agley" with a less dialectical word.

Comment: "Is gone" is only barely into the category of archaisms, and might well have been an acceptable translation in 1785, if the Bard of Ayrshire had written those words, which, I think, he did not, not least because the Scots 'has (or is) gang agley' translates as nonsense - 'has (or is) go awry', that is, 'gang' is the base or infinitive form). Third-person singular present gangs, present participle gaun, past gaed, past participle gaen. The text quoted is from 'Concerning Cats' (1900) by the American Helen M Winslow.

Comment: Nothing archaic about "is gone", I assure you, although most people would probably say "has gone" -- but they'd usually contract that to "[something]*'s gone* [wrong|awry|agley]" anyway.

Comment: I don't mind using 'is gone', and have become used to being 'corrected' by people who don't read much.

Comment: My point is that Ms Winslow's character was speaking cod-Scots of the "Hoots mon" variety. Whether this is intentional I cannot tell. To write 'the world's gone wrong' in Scots you would need 'the world's **gaen** agley' - example: The weary sun's **gaen** down the west,
The birds sit nodding on the tree;
All nature now prepares for rest,
But rest prepared there's none for me. -The Soldier's Adieu (Robert Tannahill. 1808)

Comment: Be cautious about calling Scots a 'dialect', especially north of the Border. The [Scottish Government](https://www.gov.scot/publications/scots-language-policy-scots-version/) considers it one of Scotland's three languages, with Gaelic and English. "We are fair blythe tae be eekin on a cuttie innins tae this Scots Language Policy. We, in the Scottish Government, are continuin tae tak important steps tae heize the profile o the Scots leid. This paper sets oot policy commitments an context, oor reasons for supportin Scots, the ettles we hae as a Government an the practical steps we will tak."

Comment: Dialect or not, you can't change anything about the text, because you are not the author. You are quoting someone else's work.

Comment: It's fake 'dialect'; I think the OP is asking whether changing **'s** to **is** preserves the meaning; discussion has ensued about the 'is gone'/'has gone' usages; I don't really think the OP is asking if it's OK to edit the original text in a quotation.

Comment: It's a shame that the other two answers were deleted by their authors, even if someone said their posts were not answers, I found them helpful and entertaining nevertheless.

Comment: You ask "Can I change it into ...". Why do you want "to change it"?  If you are _quoting_ it, then you shouldn't change it - else it's a false quote!  If you're writing something similar yourself, then you can write & use whatever wording you want.

Answer (score 17):

*The best-laid schemes o' mice an' men 
gang aft agley* is a well-known line from the Scots poet Robbie Burns.

It appears in ["To a Mouse, on Turning Her Up in Her Nest With the Plough, November, 1785"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_a_Mouse).

The Wikipedia provides a translation from Scots to English, which is a tad snarky in my view, but possibly helpful for those raised outside the British Isles.

When a character in fiction uses Scots dialect, you can be sure that they heard this phrase in their (fictional) childhood. Same with the author.

The easiest translation of *gang agley* is *go awry*. There are, of course, **many** ways of expressing this concept (some mild, some extremely vulgar), because as Burns aptly notes, it happens often.

Comment: That's an intriguing point about both the fictional character and the author hearing the dialect in childhood. But they must have heard it from someone, likely an adult. Are you referring to contemporary authors and their characters?

Comment: Re: "The Wikipedia provides a translation from Scots to English, which is a tad snarky in my view, but possibly helpful for those raised outside the British Isles": As an American, I can confirm that I wouldn't be able to understand the poem without that translation. (And I don't think it's at all snarky; on the contrary, giving an "English translation" implicitly acknowledges that Scots is a proper language. I think Burns would be quite happy with that.)

Comment: @ruakh - 'giving an "English translation" implicitly acknowledges that Scots is a proper language.' Yes. see my comment above. I don't think you would exactly get scowls in Scotland (yet) for calling Scots a 'dialect', like you might in Catalunya if you said that Catalan was one, but it is something careful speakers should be aware of.

Comment: Regarding that “snarky” or not translation, it may be worth noting that Wikipedia has _an entire Scots-language encyclopedia_. And while I find I can understand *most* of Scots, “gang agley” was beyond me. Anyway, I suspect most Americans would be surprised to learn that the phrase “Of Mice and Men” wasn’t a Steinbeck original.

Comment: I would have liked Global Charm's answer better if he/she had either explained what he/she means by 'snarky', and why the Wikipedia translation has that quality, or else omitted that statement of opinion.